# column not found on comboBox filter

Tags: c#, winforms

I keep getting an error on my comboBox that says it cannot find the column. I am not sure why this is because the dataGrid is visible on the screen and that is indeed the name of the column.
Below is the code for the filter on the comboBox:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Item_number  LIKE '%{0}%'", comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString());
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;


    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the exact error message you get? What are the exact contents of `comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()`? Does `dt` have data at that point? Where is it populated?

Comment: this is the error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot find column [Item_number].`

Comment: So the error message is pretty straightforward. Does `dt` have that column?

Comment: I saw my error based on your comment @Andrew. I wrote the code incorrectly. It should have been:
`(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Item_number LIKE '%{0}%'", comboBox3.Text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw my error. I wrote my code without passing values to dt.Rewriting ficed my issue:

```
    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Item_number LIKE '%{0}%'", comboBox3.Text);

    }
```

Comment: I bet the confusion was because you thought `dt` would stay populated between different requests, and that's not true unless you specifically store it in the `ViewState` or `Session`. I'm glad you solved it.